# Store.add does not make the call to the server in ExtJs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

​I am trying to insert a new record by doing `store.add` ​followed by `store.sync()`. But it does not make the call to the server . But when I load an existing record and change it and do `store.sync` it does work. My store looks like this below :

```
            Ext.define('app.store.MyStore', {
                extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
                model : 'app.model.MyModel',
                storeId : 'MyStore',
                autoLoad: true,
                pageSize : 50,
                proxy : {
                    type : 'rest',
                    actionMethods : {
                        create : 'POST',
                        read : 'GET',
                        update : 'PUT',
                        destroy : 'DELETE'
                    },
                    root : 'results',
                    url : 'my_url',
                    reader : {
                        type : 'json',
                        root : 'result',
                        totalProperty : 'totalCount',
                        messageProperty : 'message'
                    },
                    simpleSortMode : true,
                }
            });
```

I am adding records as below :

```
store.add (new app.model.MyModel (
    {
        'field1' : val1, 
        'field2' : val2, 
        'field3' : val3
     }
     );
```

Comment: You didn't post the code that show you adding the record.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see writer in your proxy config. Whenever you want to send data to server, you should configure writer in proxy.

```
Ext.define('app.store.MyStore', {
                extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
                model : 'app.model.MyModel',
                storeId : 'MyStore',
                autoLoad: true,
                pageSize : 50,
                proxy : {
                    type : 'rest',
                    actionMethods : {
                        create : 'POST',
                        read : 'GET',
                        update : 'PUT',
                        destroy : 'DELETE'
                    },
                    root : 'results',
                    url : 'my_url',
                    reader : {
                        type : 'json',
                        root : 'result',
                        totalProperty : 'totalCount',
                        messageProperty : 'message'
                    },
                    writer:{
                        /*configure writer as per your requirement*/                    
                    },
                    simpleSortMode : true,
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Store.add method Adds model instance to the Store, hence it accepts an array of Model instances or Model configuration objects.

If you want to make a Ajax call to the server then you should use store.load rather than store.add

[see the link for reference](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load)